# Why is that CSS didn't include variables from the beginning (and until now)?

Tags: css, variables

I've played with a lot of useful tools like HAML and LESS that gives CSS the capability of creating variables. I'm wondering why this feature wasn't included when CSS started. Is it too redundant or is not really necessary for some reason?

Comment: I don't know, but I think it's asinine CSS didn't begin with center div horizontally and vertically. Even PowerPoint has that!

Comment: @mcandre: For horizontal centering: margin: 0 auto; and for vertical there are a couple of ways of doing it: http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/

Comment: @Alerty: Those are hacks. Themeforest gives five examples, because none of them are standard. Clearly, the designers of CSS didn't think centering was a necessary feature.

Comment: @mcandre: Those are not hacks except of what is done for IE (which rarely follows the standards anyway).

Comment: @mcandre: Before saying the designers of CSS didn't think about something, go read W3C standards on CSS. http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center#vertical

Comment: "CSS level 2 doesn't have a property for centering things vertically. There will probably be one in CSS level 3." Keyword is "probably". They still don't think it's that important. And the example given is yet another hack. By using display: table-cell, CSS is reverting to old school HTML tables. Am I the only one who finds this laughable?

Comment: @mcandre: So using a combination of properties is a CSS hack to you?

Comment: @Alerty: Yes, because there shouldn't need to be a combination of properties. Vertical and horizontal spacing each occur on a single axis, a single dimension, a scalar, a property, an atom of description. By mathematical, logical, and conventional human reasoning, these uni-dimensional characteristics should be configured by single CSS attributes.

Comment: @mcandre: The concept of Cascading Style Sheets is to allow flexibility. A cascade of properties, in other words, a combination of properties one on top of the other will allow the web designer/developer that flexibility. Therefore, a combination of properties is not a hack, but the essence of liberty that one can use to create wonderful creations and it is the definition of CSS.

Comment: @mcandre: There is a vertical-align property. Many do not know how to use it properly or know when to use it. One reason is that it can specify at least two different behaviors depending where it is used. Anyway, there are many ways to center vertically what ever one wishes to align vertically and it is best, in my opinion, to give one the liberty to do what they wish than to force one single property.

Comment: By that logic, there should be one, a hundred, any number of ways to perform a simple task. This isn't an example of liberty. This is another Rube Goldberg machine.

Comment: @mcandre: Maybe you can not see the art of expression in a Rube Goldberg machine and neither can see it in CSS. I feel free to express the design I wish with CSS. The problem is the different interpretation of it by the many available browsers.

You should also note that HTML layout was not designed to specify vertical behavior. It scales according to width and the content flows to an appropriate height based on the available width.

Comment: Yes, Rube Goldberg machines are artistic. They're supposed to be. CSS specification is not supposed to be artistic. Should the very bristles of a paintbrush be sculptures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because CSS wasn't really perceived as a programming language.  HTML doesn't have variables either.  Variables are often only seen as really necessary if you're going to manipulate them after you create them.

Comment: I agree. CSS has been really simple, and accessible to the majority of people. Although now I see it turning into more of a programming language, since CSS introduced it's first interactive classes. Something as simple as :hover is going to get much more functionality with CSS transitions and such.

As much as I enjoy it, I think HTML and CSS should be kept as the design layout layer, and a separate language (javascript) should be used for interactions on a webpage.

Comment: @danixd: I agree, for the most part. Is it possible to embed JavaScript in a style sheet, though? Because I can see how that could have some potential usefulness.

Comment: @JAB: In fact, it is best not to mix JavaScript and CSS. JavaScript can be disabled on a user's browser and that would mean a broken style for the site... a very ugly mess. On the other hand, you can use a server side language such as PHP for that (have a look at my answer).

Comment: @Alerty, CSS can be turned off too

Comment: @Malfist: And that would create an even bigger mess ;)

Comment: @Malfist: Actually, I am rather impressed that it is possible to turn CSS off. CSS does not represent a security risk in any way (that I am aware of) because it is a style sheet and has nothing to do with programming language.

Comment: It's for accessibility that it's able to be turned off. You can actually specify css in the browser that will override anything on the page. Back when I was reading a lot of stuff online for classes, I'd override page colors to make it look more like the Zenburn theme which is a lot easier on your eyes.

Answer (score 2):

Bert Bos written up his position in [Why “variables” in CSS are harmful](http://www.w3.org/People/Bos/CSS-variables.html), the other side is nicely represented by [CSS Variables Are The Future](http://alex.dojotoolkit.org/2008/08/css-variables-are-the-future/).

Bos' arguments range from weak to vacuous.

Comment: "# number of CSS style sheets: 25725", "# number of non-empty style sheets: 24805" Is there any purpose to those 920 empty style sheets?

Comment: no.  have you never seen a careless programmer remove the last remaining few lines from a file and leave the file instead of removing it altogether? ;)

Comment: @JAB It means he's using a non-representative sample.

Answer (score 1):

Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) is not a programming language. At first, CSS was developed as a means for creating a consistent approach to providing style information for web documents. This purpose has not changed since CSS1. It is used to describe the presentation semantics of a document for certain markup languages (HTML, XHTML, XML, etc.).

What is great is that it is possible to create variables! One approach would be to use a server side language such as PHP and create some 'dynamic CSS'. Now there are several ways of doing so and here are some sites about that...

- http://davidwalsh.name/css-variables-php-dynamic
- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-add-variables-to-your-css-files/

I find it useful to use 'dynamic CSS'. Here are a few examples: you can allow users of a site to change certain aspects of it such as font-size, you can change the style of the site even more easily, you can offer different style themes for a site, etc. The possibilities are endless.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for a good question. What you're asking for is not redundant and is certainly on the top of most CSS practitioners' wish lists (along with selector nesting).

I think this is another case of a very complicated standard that crawled to the finish line for its first release, and then, for one reason or another, it was too much effort to add certain very-nice-to-have features. The cascade itself must have been a beast for the designers to architect and browser makers to implement.